# Visual Studio, static page tab width

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I find myself having to close multiple files in a project sometimes, and because visual studio adjusts a page tab width according to the respective file name length, I have to move my mouse left or right for each tab to get to the "X" for close. This can be annoying after a few times. Yes there is "close all but this" but sometimes i want i keep some tabs that are to the left. Is there a setting for this? Or an extension that adds this sort of behaviour (Similar to what you get in Google Chrome, and most popular browsers where tabs are the same width)?

Comment: Try the Productivity Power Tools extension.  It adds an option to "Close All But Pinned" tabs.

Comment: @BJMyers good idea. But Im not too comfortable with any extra steps hey, would be good to just have the tabs be the same width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com) (commercial, developed by me) to have fixed tab width (style TabInternals to have fixed width). It also has an add-in to close all tabs to the right of the selected tab.